# Android - Writing directly to external sd card without passing thru file system

Tags: android, java-native-interface, sd-card, android-sdcard

I'm trying to read directly from external sd card, with android OS.
When I open a file:

```
int fd = open("/sys/block/mmcblk1", O_RDONLY);
```

It succeed.

But when I try to read from it:

```
char buffer[4096];
//jbuffer_size = 4096
bytes_read = read(fd,buffer, jbuffer_size);
```

It returns "permission denied".

Comment: @iTech - more than just that, is the code in question running as root?  Even on "rooted" devices that is not usually the case, as you cannot really run an application's process as root, but only launch a native helper process which does.

Comment: well.. how can I run anative helper process with root permission? And why can I open() that file and get a valid fd if i dont have the permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have written "/dev/block/mmcblk1" instead of "sys"

Answer (score 1):

You need the correct permissions to read an external file. Try adding the permission "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" to your Android Manifest.